# Why am I receiving the error "start of central directory not found" for copied zips

Tags: java, zip, corruption

I’m recursively unarchiving zip files in memory, reading and injecting content into any found placeholders, then packaging them all back up again and creating an output file.

Here’s the method in question:

```
public void unpackZipFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(in);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bout);
    for (ZipEntry entry = zin.getNextEntry(); entry != null; entry = zin.getNextEntry()) {
        if (entry.isDirectory() || entry.getName().startsWith("__MACOSX/")) continue;
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(entry.getName()));
        processInputStream(zin, zos);
        zos.closeEntry();
    }
    zos.close();
    bout.writeTo(out);
}
```

Unfortunately, most zip unarchivers are complaining about the resulting file.
An example of this would be:

```
warning [1-master.zip.data]:  1198 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
(attempting to process anyway)
error [1-master.zip.data]:  start of central directory not found;
zipfile corrupt.
(please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

The unarchivers that aren’t complaining, however, produce exactly what is expected. None of the files seem corrupted, the contents are as expected, and they run as expected. The only files that seem impacted are the zips themselves, which all have this problem regardless of if they were the outermost zip or nested.

I’ve been attempting to uncover what the issue could be for the past several days without luck and figured a fresh set of eyes might help shed light on my ignorance.

Edit: The entire class: https://gist.github.com/justisr/0b127182fb143c06a1888f83a628995f

Comment: Presumably you close the OutputStream `out` at some point? [Actually closing the zoo does that] What happens if you just copy each entry without making any modifications, are the resulting zip files ok?

Comment: I'm wrong, closing the zos is closing the baos, you will still need to close `out`.

Comment: I see no recursion in that code. Where do you believe you implemented recursion?

Comment: Why is the `ZipOutputStream` writing to `bout` instead of writing directly to `out`? Was anything done with `out` before calling that method? You should show us the caller, and how `in` and `out` are created.

Comment: @tgdavies Yes, it is closed after all available bytes have been read.

Comment: Andreas, processInputStream determines the type of file that the entry is, determines how to process it, and passes it off to the relevant functions. If the file is a zip, it is passes the streams back to unpackZipFile. Hence the recursion.

Comment: @Andreas Here’s the entire class: https://gist.github.com/justisr/0b127182fb143c06a1888f83a628995f

Comment: Have you tried running this making no modifications to the zip data? Are those zip files corrupt?

Comment: I also don't like the look of the buffer member in a class that's recursive -- what if copyReplace recourses via a populate implementation? The buffer is not that large, just allocate it in each method when you need it, don't share it.

Comment: @tgdavies I had run it with the directory/macos exclusion commented out, so that those entries are included in the output file, but the error did not change. Moreover, the populate method always returns its own buffer instance, never the shared buffer. I intend on redesigning this later, but at the very least, it’s not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class file provided by Justis gives us an inkling as to what's going wrong here.

https://gist.github.com/justisr/0b127182fb143c06a1888f83a628995f

```
public void processInputStream(String loc, InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    if (processLocation(loc)) {
        switch (parseFormat((PushbackInputStream) (in = new PushbackInputStream(in, 8)))) {
        case CLASS:
            processClassFile(loc, in, out);
            break;
        case EMPTY_OBJECT:
            copy(in, out);
            break;
        case OTHER:
            copyReplace(in, out, loc);
            break;
        case RAR:
            copy(in, out);
            break;
        case ZIP_OR_JAR:
            unpackZipFile(loc, in, out);
            break;
        case SCHEMATIC:
            break;
        case PNG:
            break;
        }
    }
    //<-- valid ZIP within output stream to this point
    copy(in, out);
}
```

With the specific ZIP file causing this issue, unneeded/arbitrary data is located at the end of the file, which the ZipInputStream knows to ignore and any call to .read() will return -1 bytes read.

However, this outer call to copy() is between the base input and output stream, reading and writing this unneeded/arbitrary data anyway, and thus corrupting the ZIP file.

Obvious fix knowing this is to use the default case and removing this outer call to copy() to ensure unneeded data isn't being written directly to the output stream.

Comment: It does seem like there was (entry?) data remaining even after all of the zip entries were added. Moving the following copy out of scope, as you suggested, does ensure that data isn’t written to the output file, and does prevent the corruption.
Will be accepting this answer, since it fixes the problem, although if anyone else has an explanation for why there was zip data remaining even after there were no more entries left, I’d like to better understand the reason for it.